# using bread machine as toaster oven

Tags: baking

Can I bake/heat some frozen spring roll in my bread machine since it has bake function and would this damage my machine?  Seems like a good toaster replacement.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

**It is unlikely to do the job well.**

A toaster oven is designed to toast: to produce relatively **high heat for short periods of time**. A bread maker is designed to bake: to produce a **lower temperature for longer periods of time**. The bread maker is also likely to trap **more moisture** inside the space than the toaster oven (especially relevant if you are using it to defrost something, since ice will probably melt and form a puddle of water which will slowly evaporate and make the space humid).

Further to that, if your bread maker is like the model in the photograph, it is limited to **preset routines** and will not give you much (if any) direct control, or even information, over temperature and time (although of course you can take things out early).

I think a bread maker should certainly defrost and heat your spring rolls safely, but if they are designed for a toaster oven the end product is likely to be worse than intended – certainly less crispy. (On the other hand, it may well come out better than in a microwave, so it depends on your point of comparison.)

Comment: I think the preset routines are the real killer here; the "bake" mode might help, or even "jam".